# Is Redis ZADD or ZSCORE atomic?

Tags: redis

If two Redis clients issue ZADD or ZSCORE commands concurrently, will it have race condition and mess up the set value? If it is not thread-safe, then I will need to protect the commands with a lock, right?

I read the [ZSET API reference](http://redis.io/commands/ZADD). Maybe I missed it, but I saw nowhere it mentions the thread-safety of ZSET commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159092/atomic-set-only-if-not-already-set). Basically Redis is single threaded and all commands will be queued and serialized, so there is no parallel command execution to worry about.